# Convert from react router dom v5 to react router dom v6 when using useRouteMatch

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having issues with what the new syntax should be when it comes to migrating from React Router V5 to React Router V6.

I am new to V6 but in V5 I was using the following code within the component name: `MyComponent.js`

**RR V5**

```
 const theRoute = useRouteMatch();
  const myRoutes = [
    ['Tab One', theRoute.url],
    ['Tab Two', `${theRoute.url}/details`]
 ];
```

**Use Case currently for V5:**

```
  <AppBar
      position="static"
      color="primary"
    >
      <Tabs
        value={location.pathname}
        textColor="inherit"
      >
        <Tab
          label={myRoutes[0][0]}
          value={myRoutes[0][1]}
          component={Link}
          to={myRoutes[0][1]}
        />
        <Tab
          label={myRoutes[1][0]}
          value={myRoutes[1][1]}
          component={Link}
          to={myRoutes[1][1]}
        />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>

    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={routes[0][1]}>
          <Main />
        </Route>
        <Route path={routes[1][1]}>
          <ShowDetails />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
```

Within `App.js` (parent level), I have a route that calls the above `MyComponent.js` component, which has nested routes.

```
<div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/info/:id">
      <MyComponent />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</div>
```

I realise that `useRouteMatch()` is no longer available in RR V6 but unsure how to achieve the same result I used in V5 above, now in V6?

I looked at `useLocation()` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: This is because `react-router-dom@6` is capable of rendering relative links and routes. How is this `myRoutes` array used? Can you share the use case?

Comment: @DrewReese - use case added to original question.

Comment: Is all that code nested in some *other* route? Is that why you previously grabbed the current route's matched URL value so you could build from it? Can you include a bit more code to fill in the picture why the nested route's path prefixes are important?

Comment: @DrewReese - I have added code relating to `App.js` route that calls the above `MyComponent.js` component. This component also has additional nested routes that I build from, from the parent level route. Hope this makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App

- Switch the `Switch` component for the `Routes` component that replaced it in v6
- Move `MyComponent` into the `Route` component's `element` prop, passed as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.
- Include a trailing route path wildcard character `"*"` at the end of the path so nested routes can also be matched by this route.

Example:

```
<div>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/info/:id/*" element={<MyComponent />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

MyComponent

- Wrap the nested routes in a `Routes` component so route matching works. Nested `Routes` components will build paths relative from the parent route rendering them.
- Move the routed children components into the `Route` component's `element` prop.
- I suggest making the code more DRY by moving the component you want to render for each route into the `myRoutes` config and convert to objects from arrays, and map the `myRoutes` config to the JSX.

Example:

```
const myRoutes = [
  {
    name: 'Tab One',
    path: "main",
    element: <Main />,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tab Two',
    path: "details",
    element: <ShowDetails />,
  },
];

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();

// Compute the "last path segment" to use for the `Tabs` component
// `value` prop. The last path segment will match against the paths
// that are used for the `Tab` component's `value` prop.

const lastSegment = pathname.split("/").slice(-1).join();

...

<AppBar position="static" color="primary" >
  <Tabs
    value={lastSegment}
    textColor="inherit"
  >
    {myRoutes.map(({ name, path }) => (
      <Tab
        key={path}
        label={name}
        value={path}
        component={Link}
        to={path}
      />
    ))}
  </Tabs>
</AppBar>

<div>
  <Routes>
    {myRoutes.map(({ element, path }) => (
      <Route key={path} path={path} element={element} />
    ))}
  </Routes>
</div>
```

Comment: `const { pathname } = useLocation();
const lastSegment = pathname.split("/").slice(-1).join();` This little bit is exactly what I needed to replace `useRouteMatch` from react-router v5. I needed to set `is-active` outside of a `NavLink`, which seems to be pretty difficult (eg: no built in hook) with react router v6. Thank you!